Probability inequality for random vector
Let $\mathbb{X}$ and $\mathbb{Y}$ be two iid random vectors on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$.
Let $\xi > 0$:
$$
\mbox{how to show that}\quad
\operatorname{P}\left(\left\vert\mathbb{X} + \mathbb{Y}\right\vert \ge \xi\right) \ge
\frac{1}{2}\,
\operatorname{P}\left(\left\vert\mathbb{X}\right\vert \ge\ \xi\right)^{2}\ ?.
$$

Hi what have you tried please include this in your post

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
